# Does an isolate / sandbox access modifier exist in any language?

Tags: oop, access-modifiers

Is there a language which has a feature that can prevent a class accessing any other class, unless an instance or reference is contained?

```
isolated class Example {

    public Integer i;

    public void doSomething()
    {
        i = 5; // This is ok because i belongs to this class

        /*
         * This is forbidden because this class can only
         * access anything  contained within, nothing outside
         */
        System.out.println("This does not work.");
    }
}
```

[edit]An example use case might be a plugin system. I could define a plugin object with references to certain objects that class can manipulate, but nothing else is permissible. It could potentially make security concerns much easier.[/edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any class-based access modifiers with such intent, but I believe access modifiers to be misguided anyway.

Capability-based security or, more specifically, the object-capability model seems to be what you want.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-capability_model

The basic idea is that in order to do anything with an object, you need to hold a reference to it. Withhold the reference and no access is possible.

Global things (such as System.out.println) and a few other things are problematic features of a language, because anyone can access them without a reference.

Languages such as E, or tools like google caja (for Javascript) allow proper object-capability models. Here an example in JS:

```
function Example(someObj) {

    this.someObj = someObj;

    this.doStuff() = function() {
        this.someObj.foo(); //allowed, we have been given a reference to it
        alert("foobar"); //caja may deny/proxy access to global "alert"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any language where you must include headers would probably count: Just don't include any headers.

However, I would wager that there's no language that explicitly forbids external access. What's the point? You can't do anything if you can't access the outside world. And, why would the reference to `Integer` be okay, but `System.out.println` not be?

If you clarify the potential use-case, we can probably help you better...

Edit for your Edit:

I thought you might be going there.

If this is for security, it's flawed from the start. Let's examine:

```
class EvilCode {
    void DoNiceThings() {
        HardDrive.Format();
    }
}
```

What incentive do I have to voluntarily place a keyword on my class? I'm certainly not going to because I'm nice, since I'm not!

One thing to consider is that any time you're loading native code that's not your own (native, in this case, means not scripted), you're potentially allowing a bad guy to run his code. No language features are going to protect you from that.

The proper answer depends on your target language. Java has Security descriptors, .NET lets you create AppDomains with restricted permissions, etc. Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in these fields.

Comment: I made an edit to the original question with a use-case, I hope it makes it clearer. I can see it is kind of ambiguous which is because I am not 100% on the implications of such a feature so I don't have a vivid picture of it.

Comment: @DaSilva: I've updated my answer. Hopefully that answers your question better.